# In Python how to schedule a job every day but skip some specific day/s

Tags: python, cron, schedule

For example I have a function:

```
def cron_job():
    schedule.every().day.at("00:00").except(0, 6, 7).do(job)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)
```

Now this scheduler line is showing some syntax error. What should be the exact syntax.
Here,
0 corresponds to Sunday
6 corresponds to Friday
7 corresponds to Saturday

Comment: Could you please add the error message that your getting to your question and a link to the schedule package that you're using?

Comment: Just a minor correction: if 0 is Sunday, then Saturday should be 6 not 7.

Answer (score 2):

In Python's [schedule](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/schedule/stable/schedule.pdf) I could find no reference to .except() method. Can you please provide a link to documentation?

The simplest solution is to schedule it every day, and in your job-function have a return None if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() in (0, 5, 6).
As another user has pointed out there is no week-day = 7.

Answer (score -1):

There's a much simpler way:

```
$ crontab -e
# 
# m h  dom mon     dow      command
  0 0   *   *   1,2,3,4,5   /home/user/script.py
```

For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)